# Which Color Space to Use for Brightness, YUV or HSL?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Assume we have a photo taken under insufficient lighting condition. The image is darker than usual but still recognizable.

Now we want to make it brighter so it looks like taken under sufficient lighting condition.

Should we convert the image into YUV and tune the Y channel (luminance), or convert to HSL and tune the L channel (brightness)?

The wording seems similar to me, while their formula differs a lot:

Y: 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B

L: 0.5*(max + min), while max/min is the max/min value among RGB

**EDIT:**

More specifically, I am going to use opencv, cv2.cvtColor(), but unsure which input argument better suits my need: BGR2YUV or BGR2HLS

Comment: what does this have to do with programming? Nothing!

Comment: This is image processing, why is it not related? @MitchWheat

Comment: image processing is not programming. where is there a coding problem in your question?

Comment: @MitchWheat I am going to use opencv, cv2.cvtColor(), but unsure which input argument better suits my need: BGR2YUV or BGR2HLS

Comment: but that is not the actual question you asked, now is it?

Comment: @MitchWheat I think they are equivalent. I will put it into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuning just Y and L (in YCbCr and HSL) will result in loosing information, like contrast between high pixel values. I will suggest either using some affine transformation on Y or L

255*(Y(x,y) - min(Y))/(max(Y) - min(Y))

or best would be to use histogram equalisation. It will not only give bright image, but with better contrast also, so it is good for visualisation